# How to view concordance of keyword in text analysis

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6, python-3.7

I have defined a function to seach for the words in a long text file, and then prints (width) characters to the left, and to the right of that keyword:

parameters:

reviews = list of the words, segmented previously

word = keyword we are looking for

width = number of characters to the left and right to look for.

```
def view_concordance(reviews, word, width):
    stringtext = ' '.join(reviews)
    charindex = 0
    while word in stringtext[charindex + len(word) + 1:]:
        charindex = stringtext.find(word, charindex + len(word) + 1)
        first = charindex - width
        last = charindex + len(word) + width + 1
        print(stringtext[first:last])
    return 'The End'
```

However, if the word I'm searching for is for example 'end', it will show any word containing 'end', like 'bend', 'tend', 'send'.

Is there a way to only look for 'end' specifically without importing regex or anything at all?

Comment: do you search for `endswith`? https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_endswith.htm

Comment: Could you try looking for ' end ' with whitespace?

Answer (score 0):

You can search for a word `w` in a string `s` by defining possible/useful word boundaries `b` and check for them as well. For example:

```
w = 'end'
b = ' .:!?'
s = 'endurance tends to be more important towards the end.'

i = 0
while w in s[i:]:
    i += s[i:].index(w)
    lb = i - 1 < 0 or s[i - 1] in b  # Left boundary.
    rb = i + len(w) >= len(s) or s[i + len(w)] in b  # Right boundary.
    if lb and rb:
        print('Found {} @ {} in "{}"'.format(w, i, s))
    i += len(w)
```